# Jersey client requires XMLInputFactory which is missing in Android

Tags: android, jersey, jackson, jersey-client

I'm trying to use Jersey with Jackson in Android, but I got the following error:

```
Could not find class 'javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory', referenced from method org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessagingBinders$MessageBodyProviders.configure
```

Here is my code:

```
public static List<Task> getAllTasks() {
  WebTarget target = client.target(TARGET).path(ALL_TASKS_RESOURCE)
        .queryParam("lang", "en");
  List<Task> tasks = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
        .get().readEntity(new GenericType<List<Task>>() {});
  return tasks;
}
```

I found out that StAX XML parser is not a part of Android, but there are some alternatives. I just don't understand why Jersey wants to stream XML, and not just fetch it from the server and let Jackson to map it to POJO?

Comment: same problem here. did you font the solution?

Comment: no, I just use good old HttpClient..

Comment: better approch from far away is to use HttpClient to make the calls to Jersey :)

Comment: see https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/jersey_2_x_client_on try an update to 2.16

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a slick way to do HTTP on Android, I would avoid Jersey (it's a little heavy IMHO) and look at libraries like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). It's an annotation based REST client library that works really well. It has support for different serializers, supports async pretty well, etc.

The guys at Square have some pretty awesome libraries, including [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) - which is a way better http library than the built-in Apache one. It even supports SPDY and HTTP2.